# Special $\zeta$-series including primes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Consider $\displaystyle \zeta_{p}(z) = \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^{z}}$, where $p  $ is prime. Actually I don't know does there some specific name for that? And what about asymptotic ? Does there some information about it?

Comment: $\log \zeta(s) = -\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s})=\sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k} = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{P(sk)}{k}$ where $P(s) = \sum_p p^{-s}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the [Prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function).